# Como puedo ignorar los tabindex del navegador?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy agregando accesibilidad algunos **input-text** con la opcion de **tabindex**, pero necesito que ignore los tabindex del navegador, es decir que de la vuelta al tabindex de inicio.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tabindex</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="registrardatos.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text1" size="5" tabindex="1">
        <input type="text" name="text2" size="5" tabindex="4">
        <input type="text" name="text3" size="5" tabindex="7">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="text4" size="5" tabindex="2">
        <input type="text" name="text5" size="5" tabindex="5">
        <input type="text" name="text6" size="5" tabindex="8">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="text7" size="5" tabindex="3">
        <input type="text" name="text8" size="5" tabindex="6">
        <input type="text" name="text9" size="5" tabindex="9">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" tabindex="10">
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Que recorra todos los tabs de los inputs y vuelve e inicie al tabindex inicial]

Comment: Dos cosas: 1.) Así no se [debería usar tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex). 2) Suena a quitarle comportamientos de accesibilidad a los usuarios.